# How to scale a custom button drawable for different screen sizes in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

I have created a custom button drawable using the following xml files:

button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled"/>
</selector>
```

button_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="70dp"
        android:height="70dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#05B402" />
</shape>
```

button_enabled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="70dp"
        android:height="70dp" />
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#05B402" />
</shape>
```

I have it like this because I apply this drawable to buttons using code like this:

```
Button b = new Button(getActivity());
b.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.button));
```

However, my problem arises in using the  tag. Naturally, this causes the button to be the same size across different screens. Is there a way so that I can scale this drawable so that it is a different size on different screens?

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes. I will edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: Do you really need `size` tag in `drawable` `xml`s?

Comment: I don't think so. But without it I don't know how to set the size of my button.

Comment: Why don't you use constraint layout?  In your layout code. It expands button dynamically based on the screen size given the right constraints?

Comment: @wick.ed could you explain a little further? Maybe show me an example of how to use this?

Comment: I just noticed you are creating the button in your java code and not xml.  I thought you meant creating a responsive button (UI wise) . apologies

Comment: Here is the link to constraint layout documentation anyway https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html. See if it maybe helpful in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know, is to create multiple xml files for the different screen sizes.

To do this,

in your `res` folder right click `drawable` folder.

goto new -> Drawable resource file[image]

it should show a form:

set the name as the exact same as the others

but add a quailifer:

[image]

this will create a new folder and xml file for that specific size.

[image]

Make the changes to each xml file in those folders to get the correct scaling

EDIT:

Found from [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But what qualifies as a small screen, large screen, etc?

Comment: @JDSal Check my Edit, From android.com

Comment: @JDSal If this answer is correct, please press the greencheck mark beside it so other users with the same issue know what fixes it. Thank you

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.